# NNを訓練する時のbatch出力にNaNが混じっている場合の対処法？(Torch or Tensorflow,Keras)

Tags: tensorflow, 深層学習, keras, pytorch

NN(Neural Network)を訓練する時に、
batch出力にNaNが混じっている場合があると気づきましたが、
optimizerのstep実行に例外が発生していません。
しかし、NaNの存在が訓練過程を不安定させたり、訓練速度や精度をダウンさせたりする事は容易に想像できますので、どう対処すれば良いのでしょうか。

Comment: 「batch出力にNaNが混じっている場合がある」とはどういう状況でしょうか？

Comment: NNのbatch単位の出力の中にNaNとなっているデータが時々あります。特に訓練の初期段階で多出します。これでloss計算やOptimizerのstepにどんな影響を与えるか気になります。ただNaNの存在はどのNNにおいても良くある現象ではと思いますので、loss関数やOptimizerの中に適切に対応していなければ、大変な事になるでしょうね。普段皆さんの対処法を知りたいです。

Comment: 「NNのbatch単位の出力」とは何を指していますか？訓練中のパラメータ値のことでしょうか？ 何らかの可視化処理を追加されているのでしょうか？

Comment: < NNのbatch単位の出力>   通常NNの入出力はみな(mini)batch単位ですよ。

Comment: 勾配消失問題のことをおっしゃっていますか？それとも別のことでしょうか？質問者さんの言う「データ」が何を指しているのか分かりませんでした。

Comment: お返答ありがとうございます。更に調べてみたら、model networkの一部のweightがNaNになっているのが分かりました。莫大なweight parameterの中にたまにはNaNになったりする現象がよく起きるのではと想像します。ただ、熟して優秀なoptimizerなら、こんな事を起こさないでしょう。気になるのは少数のNaN parameterがNNの品質や訓練収束の速度をだめにする事ですね。【⚡】あるweightがいったんNaNになったら、永遠にNaNになります。理論的にも実験的にもそうであるのは分かりました。∵　weightに関するgrad計算とweight更新はNaNではできないので、永遠にNaNの状態になっていきます。非常に不都合な現象です。　ただ、量的に圧倒的ではなければ、一種の天然的な『間引き(dropout)』かなとも考えられます。しかしunder controllでなければ、やはり不安。。。

Comment: 勾配消失問題とNaNとはまったく違う概念です。